# Why are my paragraphs not indenting? (LaTeX)

Tags: indentation

Simply put, none of my paragraphs are indenting and I can't find what package is causing the issue. What only thought is to have a set of fresh eye see what my problem is.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{listings} %code
\usepackage{siunitx} %degrees
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indents paragraph after a section
\usepackage{parskip} %skipline after paragraph
\counterwithin{figure}{section} %for figure nums by section
\counterwithin{table}{section} %for table nums by section
\usepackage{minted} %For formatting code within doc
\usepackage{amsmath} %Maths tings
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Wrapped figures
\graphicspath{ {./images/} } %image directory
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{natbib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Page Margins %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\usepackage{geometry} %
\geometry{a4paper, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Header and footer formatting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{AENGM0029}
\rfoot{19044885}
\usepackage[bf, sf]{titlesec}
```

As always, help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Try removing `parskip` package

Comment: Perfect, that sees to have fixed the issue!